# How to delete multiple rows?

Tags: database, codeigniter

So I can delete one row using:

```
$this->db->delete($tableName,array("id"=>4));
```

...but I can't figure out how to delete multiple rows. I tried:

```
$this->db->delete($tableName,array("id"=>4,"id"=5));
```

as well as:

```
$this->db->delete($tableName,array(array("id"=>4),array("id"=5)));
```

...but they both don't work. I feel like this should be pretty easy. Any answers?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
$names = array(4,5);
$this->db->where_in('id', $names);
$this->db->delete('mytable');
```

Comment: How can I delete multiple records with delete condition on multiple columns like delete from tbl where col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2; I have this condition in multidim array

Comment: great finding ..!! this was not documented in CI docs. Works like a charm

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

not need of associative array.

```
$ids[] = 1;
$ids[] = 2;

$this->db->where_in( id, $ids );
$this->db->delete('Table_Name');
```

Answer (score 4):

write custom query for it

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `id` IN(1,2,3,4,5)");
```

Comment: This looks like it should work as it's the manual version of @MoyedAnsari's answer which uses CI's where_in function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

it is not work

```
$names = array(4,5);
$this->db->where_in('id', $names);
$this->db->delete('mytable');

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN ('4,5')
```

notice one thing not single string/digit ('4,5') we should be dived each and every id with single quotation like this  ('4','5')

The best and good way

```
        //$ids = 1,2,3.....
        $ids_exp = explode(',',$ids);
        $this->db->where_in('id',$ids_exp);//
        $this->db->delete('table_name')
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

the above query will be work enjoy..........

Comment: why return always 1 when using return $this->db->affected_rows();

Answer (score 1):

To delete a single use row:

```
$this->db->delete('TABLE_NAME', array('id' => 5));
```

Have you tried doing this? I'm pretty sure it should work.

```
$this->db->delete('TABLE_NAME', array(array('id' => 5), array('id' => 3), ...));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'll answer it since I had to research the same question 8 years later.

I checked the source code of `$wpdb->delete()`, and it will basically only delete 1 row. It works by matching 1 col to 1 val, and then joining with AND. So if you do `array("id"=>4,"id"=>5)`, it will read it as row with (id==4 AND id==5). No rows will match that condition.

So to delete multiple rows, the only way (as far as i've seen) is to use a custom query:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `id` IN(1,2,3,4,5)");
```